# Execute a function in a new process node

Tags: node.js, process, fork

I am looking for a way (a npm module or a lib would be really useful) to run a javascript function in a new process. However, I don't want to define this function in a different file. I am looking for something like the POSIX `fork` mechanism.

how can I achieve this in node?

Comment: Use `child_process` https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

Comment: `child_process` doesn't take in input a function but a command or file.js

Comment: Running via a separate module might be simpler, but if you must have it all contained in one file you could feed your script a parameter. I'll add an answer to illustrate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can fork new processes using [child_process.fork](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html). It accepts a separate module, but if you must have it all contained in one file you could give your script a mode parameter:

```
var child_process = require('child_process');
var mode = process.argv[2] ? process.argv[2] : 'default';

var modes = {
    default: function() {
        console.log('I am the default, I will fork a child');
        child_process.fork(__filename, ['child']);
    },
    child: function() {
        console.log('I am the child!');
    }
};

modes[mode]();
```

Comment: I see. Interesting approach, but this looks to me more an hack.

Comment: Thanks Andrew about heroku restore improbement answer.